# How to convert numeric results in symbols or strings?

Tags: matlab

this is my problem.
I made an algorithm that makes permutations of certain words. I substituted each word with a numeric value so I can make arithmetical operations with them (e.g. 1 = 'banana' 2 = 'child' 3 = 'car' 4 = 'tree' etc.).
Let's say that after running an algorithm, matlab gave me this matrix as result:
ans = [2,2,1; 4,3,3]
What I never can figure out is how to tell him - substitute digits with symbols and write:

ans = [child,child,banana; tree,car,car] - so I don't have to look up every number in my chart and replace it with a corresponding word!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array with your words, and another array with the indices, you can produce an array that replaces every index with the corresponding word like so:

```
words = {'banana','child','car','tree'};

numbers = [2 2 1;4 3 3];

>> words(numbers)
ans = 
    'child'    'child'    'banana'
    'tree'     'car'      'car'
```

Comment: shit - I used a zero! what now?! It says Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. I'd really like to avoid rewriting all the commands from the algorithm...if it's possible

Comment: @Davor: If the code simply starts counting at 0 instead of 1, use `numbers+1` to index. If the zero indicates a space or dummy word, prepend `words` with a dummy word and use `numbers+1` to index.

Comment: thank you very much - I wrote A = ones(m,n) and added it to the matrix I was using - it is functioning wonderfully. I can finally start with my composition now.

Comment: @Davor: If you add 1 to an array, it will be added to every element of the array. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I was supposed to do that - very gladly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [ordinal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ordinal.html) datatype if you have the statistics toolbox.

```
>> B = ordinal([2 2 0; 4 3 3], {'banana','child','car','tree'})
B = 
     child      child      banana 
     tree       car        car
```

Note that it handles zeros automatically.  Then you can do things like:

```
>> B=='child'
ans =
     1     1     0
     0     0     0
```

Comment: Oh thank you Rich C! I hope you don't mind, but I gave already vote to Jonas. This is helpful as well.

Comment: that's neat! Did not know about that function. Looks like for indices <=1, it sets to the first label and indices >= max # labels, sets it to the last label. For e.g., replacing the first row by `-1 -1 5` returns `banana banana tree`.

Comment: @yoda: the # unique elements in the matrix must match the number of labels.  The assignment is based on the sorted "order" the unique elements in the matrix.  If your data has no natural order, you can use catagorical arrays instead.